# Why is $DSPACE(\log^2n)\subseteq DTIME(n^{\log n})$?

Tags: time-complexity, turing-machines, space-complexity, transducers

I am having trouble with the statement that $DSPACE(\log^2n)\subseteq DTIME(n^{\log n})$ holds which is given without argument in the paper [The structure and complexity of minimal NFA's over a unary alphabet](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-54967-6_67) in the proof of Theorem 3.2.

I only get to something like $DSPACE(\log^2n)\subseteq DTIME(\log n)$. (Using the usual line of arguments to count configurations as given in the answer to [this related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97296/understanding-dspacesn-subseteq-dtime2osn).

In the paper above it is also mentioned in the same abstract that a TM transducer with operating with space in $O(\log^2 n)$ produces an output of length $O(n^{\log n})$. This too, I can not follow.
Assuming an input tape of length $n$, a working tape of length $\log^2 n$, $|Q|$ states, and $|\Sigma|$ symbols; I count a total of:

- $n*\log^2 n$ positions the TM can be in,
- $|Q|$ states to be in (constant for this examination)
- $|\Sigma|^{\log^2 n}$ working tape configurations.
  Resulting in a total of $n*\log^2 n*|Q|*||\Sigma|^{\log^2 n}$ configurations the transducer can be in .
  This gives me $O(n\log^2 n\log n)$ as an upper bound for the output length of a transducer with $O(\log^2 n)$ space.
  The paper however claims $O(n^{\log n})$.

I am confused. Please help me understand why. Thanks!

EDIT: It seems my confusion might simply be a result of me thinking $\log^2 n = \log\log n$ ... but what is meant is $\log^2 n = (\log n)^2$? o.O

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that $\log^2 n$ normally means $(\log n)^2$, unless context indicates otherwise.

The result follows from the fact that $DSPACE(f(n)) \subseteq DTIME(2^{f(n)})$ (proven by using the fact that if a deterministic algorithm repeats the same state twice, then it loops infinitely).